# How can I delete a DNS record using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dns, wmi

I was looking for a way to remove a **DNS** record specifying just the name of the record.
Maybe first **nslookup** the name, search for the **FQDN** to know the **zone**, ask for confirmation and then delete it.

Every webpage suggest to use **DNSCMD**, but that's an external resource, I want to do this all in **VB.NET** code, maybe using some references/libraries.

Is there a way to do this with **WMI** calls internally?

Answer (score 0):

```
' Connect to the WMI Service
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\dc01rootMicrosoftDNS")
' Run a query to get the record we want to change
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType" & _
  " WHERE ContainerName='thezone.net' AND OwnerName='test.thezone.net'",,48)

' Loop through the results
For Each objItem in colItems
  ' Modify the record
  objItem.Modify objItem.TTL, "1.2.3.4"
Next
```

also [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_dns_delete_a_resource_record)!

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like you are modifying the record to the IP "1.2.3.4", not deleting it. @r.r

Comment: And I'm also getting an error: "Cannot create activex component" ... I searched it and it seems that it is not recommended to do it this way. But then when I try to do it with ManagementObject, I get many many "access denied". @r.r